# cannot build photo editor sample, mdmerge.exe failed

Tags: c++-winrt

Downloaded Cpp-Winrt PhotoEditor Sample from GitHub

Failed on Buld
1- Updated Nugget package for Win2D
2 -Retargeted project for latest SDK

No changes made just tried to build it out of the box.

Final lines of build where the error is

\windows.system.profile.profilesharedmodecontract\2.0.0.0\windows.system.profile.profilesharedmodecontract.winmd
1>Processing WinMD c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\references\10.0.17763.0\windows.system.profile.systemmanufacturers.systemmanufacturerscontract\3.0.0.0\windows.system.profile.systemmanufacturers.systemmanufacturerscontract.winmd
1>Processing WinMD c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\references\10.0.17763.0\windows.system.systemmanagementcontract\6.0.0.0\windows.system.systemmanagementcontract.winmd
1>Processing WinMD c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\references\10.0.17763.0\windows.ui.viewmanagement.viewmanagementviewscalingcontract\1.0.0.0\windows.ui.viewmanagement.viewmanagementviewscalingcontract.winmd
1>Processing WinMD c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\references\10.0.17763.0\windows.ui.xaml.core.direct.xamldirectcontract\1.0.0.0\windows.ui.xaml.core.direct.xamldirectcontract.winmd
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.targets(255,9): error MSB3075: The command "mdmerge.exe @D:\Development\Projects\Sample Peojects\Winrt\PhotoEditor\Windows-appsample-photo-editor-master\x64\Debug\PhotoEditor\mdmerge.rsp" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.
1>Done building project "PhotoEditor.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Any help much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Error code 5 translates to [ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). Have you tried what the error message told you? (*"Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command."*)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention. I already ran older copy of PhotoEditor  with no issues, this is a fresh download from your github page. I run on this PC as Admin, and i never had to change any rights anywhere to get the old copy to build.

Comment: Excuse me if am no expert on the tool chain behind Winrt, but other than running this on pc where i am admin, i am not sure what rights its asking for, and am not at this time trying to be an expert on the Winrt tool chain, just keeping it to sample code for now.  And again i had no such issues last time i ran older version of same sample. And its unusual to download sample code thats giving rights errors

Comment: Maybe someone who can help comes along thanks. The sample should build in Visual Stuido straight out of the box. And the older version i tried did just that. So why isnt this one. If you know what particular  rights its looking  for this time please explain if you are expert on Winrt tool chain, i am admin on this pc.

Comment: Try running [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find out, which operation fails and why. This will help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: Hi i just tried a brand new Winrt BlankApp  template project and it has the same issue. I think there is something internal to winrt wrong,  I should be able to build the template project without any changes. I have been doing this for 3 years. Could pls try using latest visual studio etc. Someone has recently made chnages to mdmerge.exe  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT/

Comment: I just fixed this problem, and its a Microsoft issue nothing to do with admin rights. MS needs a more disciplined approach to updates. Whoever did latest winrt update broke it.  And i just had to recover from same issue with win10. MS updates are breaking things too often. Less updates more testing

Comment: If you know the answer you are invited to use the *Post Your Answer* button.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not resolved by the latest Winrt Update either. Only way to resolve is rollback winrt Nugget in Visual Studio.

As far as am aware, any Winrt project template will not build, until you go into Nugget and roll back your winrt version. I used the one just before the latest, builds fine.

Nugget saved the day.